# Windows Resource Monitor does not work with Junction Points

Tags: windows, ntfs, disk, junction, resource-monitor

Several of the observations that the Windows Resource Monitor provides is the disk queue length, latency, and throughput.  However, only partitions that are assigned drive letters show up in the Resource Monitor.  Therefore, disks that are used as junction points are not monitored.  I've tried searching Microsoft and Google for any information pertaining to junction points and the Resource monitor, but have turned up very little on the subject.  Is there a way to make the resource monitor show all partitions, without having to add a drive letter?